# Creating an euclidean distance matrix of tensors

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have 10000 of matrixes with the shape (32, 32, 3). I want to create an euclidean distance matrix between all the matrixes. At the end, it is going to be like,

```
[0, d2, d3, d4, ...]
[d1, 0, d3, d4, ...]
[d1, d2, 0, d4, ...]
[d1, d2, d3, 0, ...]
```

How I can make it in the fastest way? I have tried the following, but it takes ages to finish.

```
import numpy as np
dists = []
for a in range(len(X_test)):
    dists.append([])
    for b in range(len(X_test)):
        dists[a].append(np.linalg.norm(X_test[a] - X_test[b]))
print dists
```

Comment: Sorry, can you add an example with a valid output ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: First, in my country we learn mathematics in french, so it's hard for me to get the main idea of your algorithm. Also, it will be easy to help you if you add an example with an input and a valid output.

Comment: The input is a matrix with 4 dimensions, (10000, 32, 32, 3). It means, there are 10000 matrices with the shape (32,32,3) each. I want to have a matrix, with (10000, 10000) shape, which is going to involve the euclidean distance between each matrix and the other matrices. I could not have an output, because it takes ages to have it. That is why I have asked this question. A person who sees the good in things has good thoughts. And he who has good thoughts receives pleasure from life.

Comment: Reshape to `(10000, 32* 32* 3)` and then use cdist/pdist?

Comment: You are trying to compute (10^4)^2/2 distances between objects with ~3000 elements each. It's going to take a long time.

Answer (score 2):

You can cut the time in half by exploiting the fact that the distance matrix is symmetrical and only compute the upper triangular portion by using using

```
for b in range(a+1, len(X_test)):
```

on line 5.

I don't see any other obvious optimizations while keeping the problem *exactly* the same, but it also seems that you're working with 32x32 images in a three channel format. That's 3072 dimensions! Why not first down-sample to 4x4, convert to HSL color space, and keep only Hue and Lightness to get a (4,4,2) "signature" for each image. If your problem is mostly about shape, you can throw away Hue too and basically work with black-and-white images.

(4,4,2) has only 32 dimensions, for a savings of 100 compared to (32,32,3). And if you did want to do the full comparison in the (32,32,3) space, you could do that only on images that are already very similar in the (4,4,2) space.

Answer (score 2):

I have read [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47124845/creating-an-euclidean-distance-matrix-of-tensors#comment81200308_47124845).

Rather than asking "Show me Divakar" I asked myself "What is this pdist/cdist stuff?" — I read about [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) and [`norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) and I came out with the following code

Import stuff:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
```

Generate a random sample, not necessarily as large as the OP's one, and reshape it as suggested by Divakar

```
In [3]: a = np.random.random((100,32,32,3))
In [4]: b = a.reshape((100,32*32*3))
```

Using the `magic` of IPython, let's benchmark the two approaches

```
In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: dists = []
   ...: for i in range(len(a)):
   ...:     dists.append([])
   ...:     for j in range(len(a)):
   ...:         dists[i].append(np.linalg.norm(a[i] - a[j]))
128 ms ± 337 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [6]: %timeit pdist(b)
12.3 ms ± 252 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Divakar's was 1 order of magnitude faster — but what about the accuracy?
Let's repeat the computations...

```
In [7]: dists1 = []
   ...: for i in range(len(a)):
   ...:     dists1.append([])
   ...:     for j in range(len(a)):
   ...:         dists1[i].append(np.linalg.norm(a[i] - a[j]))
In [8]: dists2 = pdist(b)
```

To compare the results, we must be aware that `pdist` computes only the upper triangle of the square matrix of distances (because the matrix is symmetric and the principal diagonal is identically equal to zero) so we must be careful in checking our results: hence I check the off diagonal part of the first row of `dists1` with the first 99 elements of `dists2` using [`allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)

```
In [9]: np.allclose(dists1[0][1:], dists2[:99])
Out[9]: True
```

The result is the same, nice.

What about an estimate of the time required for 10,000 elements? The feeling is that's quadratic, but let's experiment doubling the number of elements

```
In [10]: b = np.random.random((200,32*32*3))
In [11]: %timeit pdist(b)
48 ms ± 97.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [12]:
```

the new timing is 4 times the initial one, so my estimate for your computation, on my feeble pc and using Divakar's proposal, is 12ms x 100 x 100 = 120,000ms = 120s.  You should read carefully [the excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47125104/2749397) by [olooney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273231/olooney) and decide what you really want to do.